Corrupted Google Tag Manager with "Unknown trigger"
My Google Tag Manager seems to reference an unknown trigger. I have several changes I'd like to get published but this error prevents me from doing anything

The "unknown trigger" link points to https://tagmanager.google.com/#/container/accounts/XXX/containers/XXX/workspaces/3/triggers/19
but the trigger of ID 19 does not exist (it even says not found in the bottom corner, and opens a broken page where I cannot really fix anything) and the page URL is automatically set t the workspace

Any idea how to fix this ?
To give you more context (although I'm not sure i'ts related) I was trying to setup a meta Pixel using the Meta wizard. At some point I have granted access so meta could push some tags on my behalf, but the workspace was dirty (I had other changes before). Meta created a bunch of tags/variables/triggers. I've tried to remove them, but the error remains. I have several changes I don't want to discard (and I get the feeling that even if I did, it would not change much...)


Export the whole container, open it raw, check triggers, find the corrupted one, remove it from the json, reupload it. Or maybe the corrupted trigger won't be exported, then just reupload it.
Try checking the tags instead. Maybe some tag still references a trigger that was removed improperly, so GTM didn't have a chance to cleanup references to it.
Dump the whole workspace and make a new one? Unless you're using the default one.
Optionally, copy your unmerged changes that you wanna keep to a different container using the tag copying extension before deleting the workspace.

Generally, automated GTM intrusions are not ideal. They rarely respect brevity and create more tags/triggers/variables than needed. Plus the naming will be completely off. Plus maybe you already have another trigger or variable that you could use instead of making one. Plus, they often forget that custom scripts deployed by a CHTML tag have to be closured.
I usually either read the description and implement their code manually, or make a new GTM container and have them dump their logic there, after which I assess it and move stuff I need to my container, refactoring and renaming it in the process.
